# c# How to use the ProcessDialogKey to capture special characters like "Tab", "Up" etc

Tags: c#, key

I want to register when the key "Tab" has been pressed, but can't figure out how to use the ProcessDialogKey.

This is what i got:

```
this.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.Keypress);    

private void Keypress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("button: " + e.KeyChar);
}
```

This can only capture regular chars, but i also need other like "Tab" etc....

So i studied a bit, and found that many had used the ProcessDialogKey, but i'm abit uncertain how to use it.

here's what i got:

```
protected  override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
{
    switch (keyData)
    {
        case Keys.Up:
            MessageBox.Show("Up");
            break;
        case Keys.Tab:
            MessageBox.Show("Tab");
            break;
        default:
            break;         
    }
}
```

I get the error: `'project.frm_test.ProcessDialogKey(System.Windows.Forms.Keys)': no suitable method found to override`

What am i doing wrong?

And bear with me... i'm used to php :)
So i'm kinda new to c# :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working, you message box is just displaying the tab character i.e. blank space.

Cast to int and you will see it's working:

```
MessageBox.Show("button: " + (int) e.KeyChar);
```

EDIT:
Otherwise look at this code:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(this.Form1_KeyPress);
    this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(this.Form1_KeyDown);            
}

// Keypress only handles keys in the ascii range
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) 
{ 
    MessageBox.Show("KeyPress: " + (int) e.KeyChar); 
}

// Keydown will work for all keys
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("KeyDown: " + e.KeyCode); 
}
```